# .NET MAUI CollectionView cannot display the string values in a list of objects

Tags: xaml, data-binding, binding, maui, collectionview

I have a Model class `Person`, which has some string properties.  In the UI, there are some `Entry` fields that, when a button is pressed, does the following in a ViewModel class:

- creates a `Person` object with the values from the fields populating the object's properties
- adds the `Person` object to an `ObservableList<Person>` , which itself is created in the constructor of the ViewModel class

I then try to display some of the `Person` object's properties in a `CollectionView` list.  A list of the string values.  I'd like it to look something like this:
[image]

I know that both the `Person` object is being created and the `ObservableList<Person>` list is being populated, as I can see the values when I step through the code.

Person.cs

```
namespace BindingDemo.Model
{
    public partial class Person : ObservableObject
    {
        #region PersonObjectProperties
        [ObservableProperty]
        private string firstName;
        [ObservableProperty]
        private string lastName;
        [ObservableProperty]
        private string email;
        [ObservableProperty]
        private string password;
        #endregion PersonObjectProperties



        public void ClearFields()
        {
            FirstName = string.Empty;
            LastName = string.Empty;
            Email = string.Empty;
            Password = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel class:

```
using BindingDemo.Model;

namespace BindingDemo.ViewModel
{
    public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public Person Person { get; } = new Person();

        [ObservableProperty]
        private ObservableCollection<Person> persons;
        
        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private void AddPersonToListAndDb()
        {
            // every field must have a value
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Person.FirstName) || 
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Person.LastName) || 
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Person.Email) || 
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Person.Password))
                return;

            // add the Person object to the list of Person objects
            Persons.Add(Person);

            // clear the fields in the UI so the user can add another person
            Person.ClearFields();
           
            // add the Person object to a database
        }
    }
}
```

View class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="BindingDemo.MainPage"
             Title="Create Person"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:BindingDemo.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:MainPageViewModel">

      <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto, Auto, Auto, Auto,*"
            Margin="10">
            <Entry Grid.Row ="0" 
                   Placeholder="Enter your first name"
                   PlaceholderColor="DarkGoldenrod"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   Text="{Binding Person.FirstName}" />

            <Entry Grid.Row="1"
                   Placeholder="Enter your last name"
                   PlaceholderColor="DarkGoldenrod"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   Text="{Binding Person.LastName}" />

            <Entry Grid.Row="2"
                   Placeholder="Enter your email address"
                   PlaceholderColor="DarkGoldenrod"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   Text="{Binding Person.Email}" />

            <Entry Grid.Row="3"                                   
                   Placeholder="Enter your password"
                   PlaceholderColor="DarkGoldenrod"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   IsPassword="True"
                   Text="{Binding Person.Password}" />

            <Button Grid.Row="4"  
                    Margin="10"
                    Text="Add to Database"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    Command="{Binding AddPersonToListAndDbCommand}"/>



            <CollectionView Grid.Row="5" 
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
                  <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                              <StackLayout Margin="5">
                                    <HorizontalStackLayout>
                                          <Label Text="First name:" />
                                          <Label Text="{Binding Person.FirstName}" />
                                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                                    <HorizontalStackLayout>
                                          <Label Text="Last name:" />
                                          <Label Text="{Binding Person.LastName}" />
                                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                                    <HorizontalStackLayout>
                                          <Label Text="Email address: " />
                                          <Label Text="{Binding Person.Email}" />
                                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                              </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                  </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
      </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

The problem is most likely in the Binding, but I don't know what else to try.

When I'm debugging, I hover my mouse over over the `Text={Binding Person.FirstName}`  to see the value of `Person.FirstName`.  Well, if I hover over `Person` I can drill down into the object and all the correct values are there, but when I hover over `FirstName`, it gives the error `children could not be evaluated`.

[image]

[image]

To illustrate that the list of `Person` objects is being created, here is an image of a watch, after I've created a few objects and put them into the list:
[image]

EDIT: this is my MainPage.xaml.cs code:

```
    using BindingDemo.ViewModel;

namespace BindingDemo
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage(MainPageViewModel mainPageViewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = mainPageViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The proper binding expression would be “{Binding FirstName}”

Comment: Where do you set the `BindingContext `? There should be a `BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();`in your code behind ctor (with reservation for that you use Dependency Injection).

Comment: @Jason that doesn't work.

Comment: @PeterWessberg I do have that.

Comment: @PeterWessberg I actually set the BindingContext in the xaml.,cs.  
public MainPage(MainPageViewModel mv)
 { InitializeComponent(); BindingContext=mv;}

Comment: @Jason when I just use "Binding FirstName" I get the error "Binding: Property "FirstName" not found on "ProjectName.ViewModel.MainPAgeViewModel"

Comment: @PeterWessberg I do use dependency injection, by the way.

Comment: Good to hear. It is better that you do an Update part in your Question and add the View code behind, since it is a part where you think it is a problem. You get a quicker answer if people don't need to read through the comments to get the whole story. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

because your `ItemsSource` is an `IEnumerable<Person>`, each row of the `CollectionView` has a `BindingContext` of the current `Person` object

that means the binding expression in the `DataTemplate` would be relative to a `Person` object, ie

```
Text="{Binding FirstName}"
```

however, because you are using compiled bindings, you also need to specify the `DataType`

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Person">
```

you will also need to add an `xmlns` declaration for `model`

Comment: Hi Jason!  I tried your suggestion.  Perhaps I didn't do the last part correctly, where you said to "add an xmlns declaration for 'model'.  I'm assuming you meant to add this line to the '<ContentPage/>' element?  'xmlns:model="clr-namespace:ProjectName.Model"'?

Comment: because I tried that (and the rest of your suggestion), and... nothing.  Same broken behavior.  Can you expand upon the statement "add an xmlns declaration for model"?

Comment: Are you getting the exact same error message?

Comment: I don't get an error message.  Nothing appears in the Label text.

Comment: That is, the value for "Text={Binding FirstName}" is an empty string.

Comment: That is because you are adding Person to the list repeatedly, then clearing it.  You need to create a new instance of Person each time you add it to the list

Comment: You are SO RIGHT!  OK, I'm gonna go fix it.

Comment: This solution does not work

Comment: You're not the one who asked the question.  If you have a similar problem but this solution doesn't work for you, then you should post a new question about it.  Simply saying that it "does not work" in a comment on someone else's question doesn't help anyone.